# Why OAuth Client Credentials Grant should not include a refresh token in response?

Tags: oauth, token, refresh-token

I am using an API Gateway proprietary tool and for registered APPs we can allow them to access a REST resource by using OAuth2 [client credentials grant.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.4)

Of course one can assume the client is [confidential](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-2.1) and we enforce the use of a confidential transport (https) but still the client needs to use always the credentials (client_id+client_secret) to get a new access token.

Why does the [Access Token Response](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.4.3) should not include a refresh token?

*A refresh token SHOULD NOT be included.*

As seen bellow the actual workflow at the stage once the client gets the access token is very similar.

### Client Credentials Grant

[image]

### Authorization Grant with refresh token flow

[image]

Comment: Section 4.4.3 https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.4.3 says specifically "A refresh token SHOULD NOT be included.".

Comment: Client credentials flow does not require user interaction. It is a simple, authenticated call to the token endpoint to get an access token. If you received the refresh token you would have to make a simple, authenticated call to the token endpoint to get an access token. It doesn't make any sense to issue refresh tokens in client credentials flows.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski then it doesn't make sense in other flows as well. You might just use Client Credentials flow and never use refresh token.

Comment: Client Credentials flow is used to get tokens representing applications, not users. If you need to get access to a user's resources then you have to use the authorization code flow and this one requires user interaction. You then receive a refresh token so that your app can get a new access token without that user interaction. Otherwise, you would have to ask the user to re-authenticate every 5 or 15 min.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski exactly, that part of the Authorization flow is machine to machine (app2app/client2resourceserver). Why it shouldn't be the same way in Client Credentials.  If you see the flow they are exactly the same at that stage an interaction between client to Auth server and client to resource server. BTW thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Going by parts:

- Why we use a Refresh Token? It is used in order to prevent the Resource Owner (a end user) to re-enter his credentials. Refresh Tokens are temporary credentials held by a client in behalf of a Resource Owner (User).

*Refresh tokens are credentials used to obtain access tokens.* [Ref](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.5)

- How to use a Refresh Token? The client application sends the Refresh Token along side his client credentials (the client must authenticate with client secret and client it) to the Authorization Server in order to receive a new Access Token.

*The client requests a new access token **by authenticating with the authorization server and presenting the refresh token**.  The client authentication requirements are based on the client type and on the authorization server policies.* [Ref](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.5)

- What happens on the Client Credentials Grant? Each time a new Access Token is needed the Client just authenticates (sending client secret and client id) to the Resource Server and gets immediately the Access Token.
- Why then the Client Credentials should not return a Refresh Token? Because it would be ambiguous. As stated before for Authorization Grant once the client wants to use the Refresh Token it will still need to send it's credentials.

What really changes is the concept. In practice the client acts a Resource Owner. It is not working on the behalf of a third party and it doesn't manage potential) multiple Resource Owners.

*The client credentials (or other forms of client authentication) can be used as an authorization grant when the authorization **scope is limited to the protected resources under the control of the client*** [Ref](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.3.4)

### Authorization Grant with refresh token flow multiple Resource Owners

[image: Authorization Grant with refresh token]

### Client Credentials Grant

[image: Client Credentials Grant]

### Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant

[image: Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant]

Note that the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant also can use a refresh token mechanism. This allows to avoid forcing the Resource Owner to re-authenticate.